# how to remove packages in using git command?

Tags: git

How to reverse the

```
git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/camel.git
```

procedure?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the machine where you ran the `git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/camel.git` command, it created a directory named `camel` and its contents in the current working directory. On Unix-like systems one can use the `rm -rf camel` command from the same working directory to delete the `camel` directory.

Answer (score -3):

To delete a repository in Github:

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. Under your repository name, click  Settings.
3. Under Danger Zone, click Delete this repository.  Say yes to all the warnings.

To remove a git repo on your local machine, delete the .git folder

```
rm -rf .git
```